# Will Ashwathama get his gem back on his forehead after the term of his curse is over?

Tags: mahabharata

In Sauptika Parva, Krishna cursed Ashwathama to be in pain for 3,000 years with all types of diseases but after the term is over, will he get his gem back on his forehead that he gave?